# Is it possible to sharpen more than 500% using unsharp mask (smart filter) without rasterizing the smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

For example could I have 2 unsharp mask smart filters stacked on top of one another?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GDSE. What effect are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?  Even just applying the unsharp mask once, by moving the amount slider to the max in the unsharp mask will be enough to almost destroy an image. Currently your question reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can have as many *Unsharp Mask* filters added to a Smart Object as you want. Try it out.

Comment: @Wolff - yeah, you can just apply the filter as many times as needed, but it's still an odd request to max out the amount at 500%, and then do it twice.

Comment: @Wolff ahh my bad!  I thought it just edited the same unsharp mask that was on the object cause it comes up with the same setting values. Thank you!

Comment: @BillyKerr the effect I was after was to focus a very unfocused object without using a new stock image. The only option is to sharpen to my knowledge!  eg. https://i.imgur.com/AbytaZt.png

Comment: You can't actually refocus an out of focus image in Photoshop. Slight blurriness due to camera shake can sometimes be fixed using Photoshop's Shake Reduction filter.  It won't work on heavily blurred or just out of focus images.  Take another photo instead which is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to a similar question

> No, you can't do it as you would like to. That request has been asked of Adobe numerous times, but afaik nothing has been done about it.

The First poster said only way to do it is to create a smart object around the initial object that had the smart filter so its like the russian dolls. Adobe please make this simpler. I guess its not needed often tho

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/multiple-smart-filters-with-masks/m-p/8669198

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question you link to. It is about if it's possible to have multiple smart filters with their own separate *mask*. *Unsharp Mask* is just the name of the filter. It's not related to masks.

Comment: No, I 100% understood the question Wolff. That's why I said 'similar'. They too wanted a separate smart filter stack applied to the same smart object. And they answered no its not possible :)  In my case i didnt even need a new stack with a mask I just needed the ability to add more than 1 of the same filter under the same stack but photoshop doesnt allow it.  They want the platform simple Im guessing

Comment: OK, then what I don't understand is why it's not working for you. I can add as many of the same filter as I want. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/au7jEV2.png). What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can build unsharp mask yourself out of a high pass filter then use levels/curves to expand it however many time you like and screen it over the object.

However it seems a bit excessive to use unsharp mask for whatever you are doing. Please note that unsharp mask is technology from 1930's, so nearly a 100 years old tech. We have way better methods for actually sharpening signals.

Or you might just you know ask about the thing you are doing.

Comment: Hi joojaa. Thank you for the tip. I just tried high pass by duplicating my object setting it to hard light and applying filter and it worked well. The only annoying thing is i have to dupliate all my objects and i have many. Unsharp mask seems the easiest. The object I was using a huge unsharp mask on was blurred and not in focus and i wanted to get it in focus. Its not perfect but I can't find a stock image I prefer to replace it. I think the most time consuming thing is finding good images that have good resolution focus and the visual look and feel i want

Comment: @12345 You can correct focus with smart sharpen that actually focuses the image.

Comment: Wow! Smart sharpen left the focused parts untouched and sharpened only what was not in focus on the object. Thats what i needed. Thanks again. You have a lot of knowledge

Comment: Actually smart focus didnt do exactly what I wanted my mask was doing the work of the smart focusing. I made to show you an example of what I needed to do to sharpen it. https://i.imgur.com/AbytaZt.png Im finding the technique doesnt work as good if the image is too low res as with another object I have it turned out a little pixlated. But theres no magic trick to add res to an image so I problem need another stock image for that issue